# Laravel belongsToMany relationship defining local key on both tables

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, laravel-4

So the belongsToMany relationship is a many-to-many relationship so a pivot table is required

Example we have a `users` table and a `roles` table and a `user_roles` pivot table.

The pivot table has two columns, `user_id`, `foo_id`... `foo_id` referring to the `id` in roles table.

So to do this we write the following in the `user` eloquent model:

`return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'foo_id');`

Now this looks for an `id` field in `users` table and joins it with the `user_id` field in the `user_roles` table.

Issue is I want to specify a different field, other than `id` to join on in the `users` table. For example I have `bar_id` in the users table that I want to use as the `local key` to join with `user_id`

From laravel's documentation, it is not clear on how to do this. In other relationships like `hasMany` and `belongsTo` we can specify `local key` and `foriegn key` but not in here for some reason.

I want the `local key` on the users table to be `bar_id` instead of just `id`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update:
as of **Laravel 5.5** onwards it is possible with generic relation method, as mentioned by @cyberfly below:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
         Category::class,
         'service_categories',
         'service_id',
         'category_id', 
         'uuid',  // new in 5.5
         'uuid'   // new in 5.5
    );
}
```

---

for reference, previous method:

I assume `id` is the primary key on your `User` model, so there is no way to do this with Eloquent methods, because `belongsToMany` uses `$model->getKey()` to get that key.

So you need to create custom relation extending `belongsToMany` that will do what you need.

A quick guess you could try: (not tested, but won't work with eager loading for sure)

```
// User model
protected function setPrimaryKey($key)
{
  $this->primaryKey = $key;
}

public function roles()
{
  $this->setPrimaryKey('desiredUserColumn');

  $relation = $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'foo_id');

  $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

  return $relation;
}
```

Comment: Will this affect other relations?

Comment: If you mean the tweak, then no. It won't affect anything but this very relation I guess.

Comment: This seems to work when getting. But when I attach, it's attaching id instead of my `desiredUserColumn`. How can I fix that?

Comment: With custom relation class only. What is that column and why you need such feature anyway?

Comment: I am importing data and all the relations were set with another key, aside from 'id' key. So now I need to make sure those relations are done properly.

Comment: That column is unique but not the primary key of the table.

Comment: or if that's too much of a hassle, how can I specify the join columns value on attach?

Like $user->roles()->attach($role_id, $user_id) or something like that? I know you can define attribute values, can you include the join column's value in the attributes?

Comment: Not really, no. Like I said, what you need is custom relation class extending `belongsToMany`. You could insert data using query builder of course, but that's another story.

Comment: Would building a custom relation class extending belongsToMany be too much of a hassle?

Comment: You need to override `attach` and `setWhere` methods, that's for sure. Maybe more, you need to check the source. Anyway it depends on your project.

Answer (score 9):

On Laravel 5.5 and above,

```
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'service_categories','service_id','category_id', 'uuid', 'uuid');
    }
```

From the source code:

```
    public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                                  $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
    {}
```

Comment: Which L5? Not in my L5.4.

Comment: Cannot edit, so adding: Not L5. L5.5 (or L5.6). It is not available before

Comment: Great it's working, Exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is a recently added feature. I had to upgrade to 4.1 because I was also looking for this.

From the [API documentation](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/):

```
public BelongsToMany belongsToMany(string $related, string $table = null, string $foreignKey = null, string $otherKey = null, string $relation = null)
```

The `$otherKey` and `$relation` parameters were added in 4.1. Using the `$foreignKey` and `$otherKey` parameters allows you to specify the keys on both sides of the relation.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is set the primary key.

```
class Table extends Eloquent {

     protected $table = 'table_name';

     protected $primaryKey = 'local_key';
```

Answer (score 0):

**belongsToMany** allows to define the name of the fields that are going to store che keys in the pivot table **but** the method insert always the **primary key** values into these fields.

You have to:

- define in the method **belongsToMany** the table and the columns;
- then using    protected **$primaryKey** = 'local_key'; you can choose which value store.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through the same problem where I needed to have an associated table that used ID's to link two tables together that were not Primary Keys.  Basically what I did was create a copy of my model that models the pivot table and set the Primary Key to the value that I wanted it to use.  I tried creating a model instance, settings the primary key and then passing that to the relation but Laravel was not respecting the primary key I had set ( using the ->setPrimaryKey() method above ).

Making a copy of the model and setting the primary key feels a little bit 'hackish' but in the end it works as it should and since Pivot table models are generally very small I don't see it causing any problems in the future.

Would love to see a third key option available in the next release of Laravel that lets you get more specific with your linking.