# Laravel belongsToMany non standard pivot column

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to setup a BelongsToMany relationship where one of the columns is not an ID reference, but rather a string reference.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'chats_users', 'chat_id', 'user_email');
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391759/laravel-belongstomany-relationship-defining-local-key-on-both-tables

Comment: If by `id` reference you mean primary key. Then make the column to primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as long as the string reference is a primary key of the parent table although it's not recommended. Be sure to check [this explanation on using strings as primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299874/can-i-use-varchar-as-the-primary-key)

```
return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'chats_users', 'chat_id', 'user_email');
```