# Laravel pivot tables with non primary keys

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, primary-key

In Laravel, I have a model which has a custom primary key. I have created a pivot table which has to use the unique incrementing key so I am unable to get any pivot data.

**Media Model**

```
class Media
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'ref_id';
    public $incrementing = false;

    ...
}
```

**Page Model**

```
class Page
{
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Media');
    }

    ...
}
```

**Pivot Table**

```
+----------+---------+
| media_id | page_id |
+----------+---------+
|     1    |    15   |
+----------+---------+
|     5    |    27   |
+----------+---------+
```

**PageController**

```
$pages = Page::with('media')->get();
```

This is resulting in the following sql statement:

```
select 
    media.*, media_page.page_id as pivot_page_id, 
    media_page.media_id as pivot_media_id 
from media inner join media_page on media.ref_id = media_page.media_id
where media_page.page_id in ('15', '27')
```

As you can see on line 4 of the sql statement, it is referencing media.ref_id instead of media.id and so obviously no results are returned. I understand why this is happening.  What I need to know is how can I update the media method in my PageController so it uses `id` instead of `ref_id` for this one query. I cannot change the primary key in the media model as this is heavily used elsewhere. I have tried the following but it seems to have no effect.

**Page Model**

```
class Page
{
    public function media()
    {
        $media = new Media();
        $media->setPrimaryKey('id');

        return $this->belongsToMany($media);
    }

    ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships you will see that `belongsToMany()` also accept other parameters to set how to join the tables `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');`

Comment: I have already tried this. `return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Media', 'media_page', 'media_id', 'id');`. This didn't work. It generated the following error. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'media_page.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select media.*, media_page.media_id as pivot_media_id, media_page.id as pivot_id from media inner join page_media on media.ref_id = page_media.id where page_media.media_id in (15,27))

Comment: Shouldn't it be return  `$this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Media', 'media_page', 'ref_id', 'media_it');`?

Comment: That then produces the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'media_page.ref_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select media.*, media_page.ref_id as pivot_ref_id, media_page.media_id as pivot_media_id from media inner join media_page on media.ref_id = media_page.media_id where media_page.ref_id in (15,27))`. I don't want to use ref_id at all. I want to remove `ref_id` from the original join statement and replace it with just `id`

Comment: Sorry, was a bit quick. The first key is the key to link to your models table, the second is to link to the other table. So not setting what you are joining from. Not sure if this is possible using eloquent, maybe you have to use query builder where you have more control on the join. You can see if this will help you some more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391759/laravel-belongstomany-relationship-defining-local-key-on-both-tables, especially the answer on laravel 5.5 where you have one more optional parameter

Comment: The accepted solution in your link is something I have already tried. I have temporarily changed the primary key in order to use the pivot table, then change it back again. It doesn't seem to make any different to the final sql statement.  How would I implement query builder with this?  The controller is calling the 'with()' method which expects an object of type 'belongsToMany' to be returned.  I probably should mention, I am running Laravel version 5.3.

Comment: It seems like you have to change the controller to use two join() or leftJoin() instead of with(). Eloquent, like most ORMs are a bit fixed on how they want a database to be structured

Comment: Thanks. As suggested, I ended up using joins in my controller. Shame I wasn't able to make full use of pivot tables by using a non primary key. Maybe that is available in future releases. I am running Laravel 5.3 which I know is pretty old now

Comment: Thanks. As suggested, I ended up using joins in my controller. Shame I wasn't able to make full use of pivot tables by using a non primary key. Maybe that is available in future releases. I am running Laravel 5.3 which I know is pretty old now

Answer (score 0):

From the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) you can pass the table name and also the foreign keys you want to use.

> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:
>
> `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');`