# Many to many Laravel Eloquent relationship with multiple intermediate tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and have a model and table structure as follows:

```
users
-----
id

accounts
--------
id

holdings
--------
id
account_id (foreign key to account)

user_accounts
-------------
id
user_id
account_id
```

- A user can have multiple accounts
- An account can be shared by multiple users
- Each account has multiple holdings
- A user therefore indirectly has many holdings through their many accounts.

**I need help to define a relation on the User model called "holdings" to get me all the holdings applicable to the user (based on the accounts they are linked to).**

I've tried lots of different things and spent ages on google. I can get close with both belongsToMany and hasManyThrough, but they only seem to work for 3 table relationships where the intermediate table stores primary keys from the other tables. I can reduce my relationship to 3 tables (rather than 4) if I make use of the account_id foreign key on the holdings table to remove the need to join through the accounts table, however I can't seem to get this to work.

belongsToMany - `holdings`.`id` needs to be `holdings`.`account_id`:

```
select * from `holdings`
inner join `user_accounts` on `holdings`.`id` = `user_accounts`.`account_id`
where `user_accounts`.`user_id` = ?
```

hasManyThrough - `user_accounts`.`id` needs to be `user_accounts`.`account_id`:

```
select * from `holdings`
inner join `user_accounts` on `user_accounts`.`id` = `holdings`.`account_id`
where `user_accounts`.`user_id` = ?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not strictly an answer as I was asking about laravel 5.4, but it is a possible solution.

It turns out I'm in luck as I came across this [Laravel belongsToMany relationship defining local key on both tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391759/laravel-belongstomany-relationship-defining-local-key-on-both-tables/47544298#47544298) which indicates the belongsToMany relationship has been enhanced in Laravel 5.5 to support this type of scenario.

I have upgraded my project to L5.5 and replaced my hack with the relation:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Holding::class, 'user_accounts', 'user_id', 'account_id', null, 'account_id');
```

And am happy to say it seems to work perfectly - at least for basic gets which is my use case, I haven't tried any updates etc.

Thanks to @cyberfly and those who posted the answer above